# Bokeh 1.4.0 whiskers not showing

Tags: python, annotations, bokeh

Hi so I've been working with Bokeh for the past two months and I just discovered that I am unable to add whiskers (error-bars) to my plots. They just do not show! Does anyone know how to fix this?

```py
myplot = figure(
    x_range=my_x_range,
    plot_width=width,
    plot_height=height,
    title=titre,
    y_axis_label=value,
    tools="save,wheel_zoom,reset,hover", 
    tooltips=TOOLTIPS
)

for val in stackers:
    base_listoflists = list(mean_df_unstack[val])
    upper_listoflists = list(upper_df[val])
    lower_listoflists = list(lower_df[val])

    whisker_dico = dict(
        base = base_listoflists, 
        upper = upper_listoflists, 
        lower = lower_listoflists)
    source = bk.models.ColumnDataSource(data=whisker_dico)
    print(source)

    mywhisker = bk.models.Whisker(
        source = source, 
        base = "base", 
        upper = "upper", 
        lower = "lower", 
        level="annotation")
    myplot.add_layout(mywhisker)    


#Plot the love
myplot.vbar_stack(stackers, 
    x='ID', 
    source=meanplotdic,
    width=0.9,
    color=cc.glasbey_dark[:len(stackers)]
    )


myplot.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi/4
show(myplot)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the full code so it's hard to say anything definite. But it works for me just fine with Bokeh 2.0.2:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Whisker
from bokeh.plotting import figure

ds = ColumnDataSource(dict(c=['a', 'b', 'c'],
                           bottom=[-1, 0, 1], lower=[-2, -0.5, 0.2],
                           top=[3, 4, 2], upper=[4, 6, 3]))
p = figure(x_range=['a', 'b', 'c'], y_range=(-3, 7))
p.vbar('c', 0.5, 'top', 'bottom', source=ds)
p.add_layout(Whisker(upper='upper', lower='lower', base='c', source=ds))

show(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I found out the problem: I hadn't been giving the right values as base, but it's all good now. Thanks anyway :)